# SU Retag Request: [startup] --> [boot]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request

[startup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/startup) might benefit from being merged to [boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with this since [startup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/startup) may refer to the startup of an application, where [boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot) is specifically about the startup of a computer.