# Use of [startup] tag unclear

Tags: discussion, retag-request

According to [SU Retag Request: [startup] --> [boot]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1923/su-retag-request-startup-boot), the [startup] tag could refer to starting either a computer or a program, but the tag wiki description of [startup] excludes it from being used for starting a program.

Should I change the tag wiki for [startup], or would that confuse people who used it in the past? I'm not sure what to do, since a previous request to merge the tags was turned down.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that there are very few occasions where a question referring to the startup of an application would benefit from the [startup] tag.

Thusly, *in my humble **opinion***, I would have supported the retag of [startup], that question has long "expired".